# Help to find demonstrations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am doing a work on Curve Shortening Flow. I want to prove some theorems that I use to deduce the existence of solution and a maximum principle to check that all the curves of the solution are convex. What I have is
$$ u_t= \frac{1}{v^2}u_{xx} $$
where $v=\langle u_x,u_x \rangle$ and
$$ u: S^1×[0,T) \to \mathbb{R}^2 $$
with $u(\cdot,t): S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. The other important PDE is for the curvature of the curves, which satisfies
$$k_t=k_{ss}+k^3$$
$s$ the arc-length parameter. The theorems for short time existence or maximal solution are for the first PDE and the maximum principle is for the second. I need help to find books where I can find proves to that theorems. Do you know any useful book?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "demonstrate" sometimes means "prove" and sometimes means "illustrate". What are you asking for?

Comment: Prove. Sorry I tranlated so bad.

Comment: @BobTerrell In French, *une démonstration* literally means *a proof* (while *a demonstration* would translate as *une manifestation*). Maybe OP's mother tongue is some related language..!